# How do I set Node.js to use relative paths for my components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I am creating a web component in Node.js. This component uses images, which I have put in a sub-directory within the component's directory.

When I import the image I get the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in Chromium. I understand that the browser wants me to use the path from the root of the project to the file, but it kind of defeats the purpose of having a nice directory structure.

I also have Snowpack installed.

Edit: Using the Node.js package `path` is difficult, since Snowpack can't normally use packages not inside the browser, and I have to use Snowpack. With `devOptions { polyfillNode: true }` it should be possible, but I tried creating a snowpack.config.js file with that line to no avail. How do I implement it?

Or how do you usually handle paths in Snowpack? I am unsure about using a polyfill, and if there is another solution, I'd be happy to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths can be used as :

```
//in ./app.js
const path = require('path');
//using path.relative()
const greet = require(path.relative(__dirname, './lib/greet.js'));
```

Same for image

```
// get the relative path of the image file from this file
const imagePath = path.relative(__dirname, './public/image.jpg');

// export a function that returns an HTML string with the image tag
module.exports = function() {
  return `<img src="${imagePath}" alt="Image">`;
};
```

Comment: Oh, okay. The problem is I must use JavaScript import, not require, and for some reason it doesn't find the path module, even though VSCode can find it. Maybe I should ask that as a separate question. Thanks for showing me how to use path, though.

Comment: have you tried npm install --save-dev @types/node &&  import * as path from 'path'; ?

Comment: I tried that now, but I get the error message
    "[snowpack] ! installing dependencies...
    [snowpack] Package "path" not found. Have you installed it?"

I suppose it's related to Snowpack. If I hover on 'path' in the import, Visual Studio Code allows me to see the definition, and it's there.

Comment: Yes the snowpack looks to be the culprit here Have a look at this : https://github.com/FredKSchott/snowpack/discussions/1981

Comment: Okay, I created a snowpack.config.js with
    `export default {
        // mount: {},
        // plugins: [],
        // installOptions: {},
        devOptions: { polyfillNode: true },
        // buildOptions: {},
    }`

I still get the same errors. Do you recommend me to use the absolute path? How does one usually do these things in Snowpack?

Edit: I'll just edit my post.